# Can we have VS2008 and VS2012 side by side?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

Is there any issues in having VS2008 and VS2012 side by side?
I usually work on VS2012, but now there is a task that requires me to build a solution in VS2008! Before I install VS2008 where VS2012 is already installed I  Just want to ensure that this does not cause issues in my Dev env.

Comment: why do you need to use VS2008? you can still build .net 2/3.5 solutions with VS2012

Comment: The code was old and was written in VS2008. This code was not touched and was supposed to be handed over to another team and we wanted to ensure that the code is handed over as is without any changes. Trying to open up in VS2012 gives a message to upgrade. Since we were not sure what more changes could go in with the upgrade and we decided to build in VS2008. But my machine already had VS2012. So this question.

Comment: the upgrade changes the sln file. use diff tool from version control to see what is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried installing VS 2008 *after* VS 2012 but on one of my machines I did it in a more typical way: first VS 2008 then VS 2010 and then VS 2012 (all 3 side-by-side) and it worked OK for me. So I'd expect that worst you might have to do is to re-install VS 2012 afterwards again.